# TypeError: Cannot read property 'title' of undefined while trying to access data from an array of objects

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mongodb, axios, use-state

I am trying to fetch data in react from mongodb using axios, I receive an array of objects on applying the GET method, but I am unable to store data in a state properly and use the data from the state in desired form, I want to fetch a particular ker's value here i.e. title. Please help me to solve this or suggest a better way of doing this.

```
 [state, setState] = useState()
 useEffect( async () =>
 {
  axios({
   "method": "GET",
    "url": "http://localhost:5500/api/add/",
   "headers": {
     "Content-Type": "application/json",
   }
 })
 .then((response) => {
   setState(response.data)
 })
 .catch((error) => {
   console.log(error)
 })

const title = state[1].title
 
console.log(title)
    }, state)
```

The data is stored in mongodb as an array of objects having key:value pairs, I received following output when I used `input - console.log(response.data[1].title)`

```
output- title-2
```

for data object:

> 1: {_id: "5f6e10d3509b062528381884", title: "title-2", details:
> "details-2", __v: 0}

After that, when I used `console.log(state[1].title)` i received

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'title' of undefined while trying to
> access data from an array of objects

Comment: What does `setState` do? from what it seems you declare `state` to be the return value of `useEffect` which is a pending promise.

Answer (score 0):

i think you are asking for  `state[1].title` before  axios returns the data and save it to  the state.
if it that the case its means you `state` is `underfined`

Comment: Yes even I think that's the case, but also it is giving output for `state[1]`, any suggestions for the solution?

Comment: do this
 [state, setState] = useState([])

and loop inside that response array and add  objects to the state.